# Delete column of certain row after finding it from script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, stock

I want to delete name, qty, price, target, sl of a stock after finding it in the data without deleting the entire row..

Currently, the code I have deletes the whole row. Please help

Eg: If it finds Auropharma, I want to delete/clear C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3 only

```
function Delete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry"); //Form Sheet
  var cell  = formS.getRange("F7").getValue();
  var dataS  = ss.getSheetByName(cell); //Data Sheet

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Delete ?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

  var str = formS.getRange("H7").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName(cell).getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var row = values[i];
      if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {

      var INT_R = i+1

      dataS.deleteRow(INT_R);
      ClearCell();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the cells to `null`:

```js
dataS.getRange(`C${INT_R}:H${INT_R}`).setValue(null)
```

If the row is 3, it gets `C3:H3` and removes its contents.

### References

- [Sheet.getRange (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Range.setValue (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Thanks but how do I incorporate it with the for loop? The C row is not constant, so how to go about it?

Comment: It should replace `dataS.deleteRow(INT_R);`. Also I'm not sure what `ClearCell()` does

Comment: Oh wow! works like a charm. Also, I have to set B2 to false (setvalue), its a checkbox @Marti

Comment: I think I figured it out -   
      dataS.getRange(`B${INT_R}:B${INT_R}`).setValue(false)

Comment: Note that you can use multiple statements. You can set false to the checkbox and null to the others. simply modify the A1 notation of `getRange`.